# How to ensure proper file permissions when running installer bash as sudo?

Tags: bash, permissions, sudo, cp

I am making a installer bash, playing with it a little too. But I just came across a serious problem: As I run the bash with `sudo ./install.sh`, all the files it copies are owned by `root` and therefore read-only for others.

This makes installed program rather useless. In my case, the installed program is Tomcat web application, meaning tomcat will not be able to use it.

Therefore the question:

Is `sudo ./install.sh` the right way installation batches should work?

- **yes:** In that case, how do I properly use `cp` command to ensure the files belong to a) issuer b) specific user. Or do I need other command?
- **no:** In this case, how do I properly perform administrative tasks (such as `apt-get install ...`) from the batch?

Comment: The `install(1)` command may be of interest to, ah, "install" files, in particular the `-o` and `-m` options to set the owner and mode...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy the files using the [install](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=install&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+8+jessie&format=html&locale=en) command. It can set owner and permissions. From the man page:

```
  -g, --group=GROUP
          set group ownership, instead of process' current group

  -m, --mode=MODE
          set permission mode (as in chmod), instead of rwxr-xr-x

  -o, --owner=OWNER
          set ownership (super-user only)
```

Comment: How can I get the owners user id and group when the script is running under sudo?

Comment: @TomášZato What user ID do you want to *get*? If the script is running as root, then the UID is 0 (root). If you want to assign a different owner to the files, use the `-o` switch. BTW: You can query the current UID with `id -u` or the user name with `id -un`.

Comment: I wanted id of the user that issued the `sudo ./install.sh` command, so that I can install the files with him being the owner. That was point of my question.

Comment: @TomášZato The user can be extracted with `SUDO_USER` and `SUDO_UID`: `sudo env sh -c 'printf "%s %s\n" "$SUDO_USER" "$SUDO_UID"'`

Comment: Actually, whatever you wrapped in caused to return `root 0`, not current user (`XXXXX 1000`). But removing the wrapper fixed the issue.